# How to tell mac OSX "osascript tell for "any device" set volume 0 ""

Tags: macos, volume, osascript

how to execute command in terminal to set volume for currect windows or application or any device.... For example to mute system vole it's simple :

```
osascript -e "set volume 1"
```

So, i got application witch aren't instaled only runing, i want to put:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Applicationame\" to set sound volume to 0"
```

1) Where to look for Applicationname? 
2) How to write correct command?

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct syntax:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Spotify" to set volume 2'
```

or

```
osascript -e 'tell app "<app_name>" to set volume <volume>'
```